# MS Teams Personal tabs are not displaying/rendering in the desktop version

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

The configured Personal tabs are displaying successfully in Teams web app/via browser. But not rendering in the desktop version. The tabs url changed in the below format to overcome this issue but not sure why this is replicating.

Tab url format: https:///_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?spfx=true&dest=/SitePages/Get-started-with-Microsoft-365.aspx

Comment: https://<tenant.sharepoint.com>/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?spfx=true&dest=</sites/lms>/SitePages/Get-started-with-Microsoft-365.aspx

Comment: are you facing any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved after configuring the "Page URL" and "Content URL" in below format:

- **For page URL:**

https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/CorporatePortal/SitePages/Home.aspx

- **Content URL must be:**

https://yourtenantname.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?spfx=true&dest=/SitePages/Home.aspx